# Remove a row based on two empty columns in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to be able to remove rows that are empty in column NymexPlus and NymexMinus
right now the code I have is

```
df.dropna(subset=['NymexPlus'], inplace=True)
```

The thing about this code is that it will also delete rows in the column NymexMinus which I don't want to happen.
Is there an If/AND statement that will work in terms of only getting rid of empty cells for both of the columns?

Answer (score 2):

Use a list as `subset` parameter and `how='all'`:

```
df.dropna(subset=['NymexPlus', 'NymexMinus'], how='all', inplace=True)
```